# How to connect an infrared remote control to PC or Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

Tags: mobile-robot, arduino, raspberry-pi

I bought my kid a [robotics kit](http://www.gigo.com.tw/english/_toy/detail.php?MID=100&SID=101&ID=974) with several motors and an infrared remote control (you can steer the robot using IR remote control).

Now I want to take it to the next level and control the robots from a PC or a Raspberry Pi.

What is the simplest approach to do this?

I am thinking about 2 possible ways:

1. Find out the protocol the existing remote control uses and then emulate the IR signals using Arduino (Arduino is sending the IR signals).
2. Find a piece of hardware, which presses the buttons on the remote control and control it via to Arduino (Arduino is sending signals to the button pushers, the remote control is sending the IR signals to the robot).

Comment: Buy them a lego mindstorms kit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Ada Fruits Tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor) along with many other sources of IR tutorials out there.

Then for an Arduino I would use (and have used) [Ken's IRremote Library](http://www.righto.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html) as it has several examples, several device protocols and requires only a [TSOP38238](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266). And is quickly adaptable to others.

Look at the GitHub Network of Forks, as there are others who have added other device protocols.